# Parameter send to filemanager

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

CKeditor and our filemanager works very well.
When I use link and image button > explore server, I have my files, so it's OK.

But, in this HTML file, I would like to know if I come from link button or image button.

So, to do this :
how can I send in the URL to my HTML file an another parameter (like the id of a element of the button : cke_xxx_uiElement)?

Comment: What is the precise question ? Please edit the question.

Comment: Re,So, to do this : how can I send in the URL to my HTML file an another parameter (like the id of a element of the button : cke_xxx_uiElement)?